# C# SqlConnection could not be found

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, .net-core

I am trying to connect to the SQL database in my network using the code below. I've searched on Stackoverflow and web for this error and found so many other people experiencing this issue, applied and tested many none fixed my issue. Currently the code I have is below:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using ( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection)
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = "Server=***;Database=***;Trusted_Connection=True;";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the place of *** I have server and database names. Also, where do I enter the specific table?

Comment: What *exact* error are you facing? You'd put the table name in the query, which you specify when you create a command. Note that you need `()` after `new SqlConnection`.

Comment: a *table* would be part of a specific query, and you aren't showing any queries; the code you've shown shouldn't compile - it would need to be `using (SqlConnection conn new SqlConnection())` (note extra parentheses) - but: the *error* suggests the problem is resolving the type itself; is this a missing reference? Are you referencing System.Data? or if this is .NET Core: System.Data.SqlClient (package reference)?

Comment: oh okay. In visual studio where there is SqlConnection text, there is red line under it when I go over it says "The type or namespace name 'SqlConnection' could not be found( are you missing a using directive oran assembly reference?) " and gives me show potential fixes but those create a new file.

Comment: I think it might be worth stopping this line of dev right now and taking a look at entity framework.. In an hour you'll be writing `command.CommandText="SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = " + Textbox1.Text;` and the fight to save another developer from spending the next 5 years writing insecure, low quality database access code will be lost :/

Comment: I changed the using line to this still doesn't work @Marc

Comment: using ( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())

Comment: Right, it'll help to open the connection. Though, I still have red line under SqlConnection...  All I did was create a new console app and enter this code to connect to DB.. What do you guys do when you need to connect the DB. Just one simple file all it does is the simplest way to connect to DB.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/get-started or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/

Comment: Add reference of System.Data in your application

Comment: @BhushanDhande that didn't fix ...

Comment: It won't fix it, because the problem is that you haven't referenced the library needed to make this code go. You're making a rod for your own back by proceeding with this particular route of database access though..

Comment: @CaiusJard when someone doesn't even know how to write a connection, or even how to add a package, telling them to cover it up with an ORM is only going to make things worse.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos would you also nip into a windows form question and assert *when someone doesn't even know how to programmatically create a UI, or even how to write gfx code to draw a button, telling them to cover it up with the windows forms designer is only going to make things worse*? Thought not.. EF, Forms designer, File.ReadAllText, Localizations system etc exist for a reason. Letting devs, particularly new ones, run riot with low level stuff is a bad idea. This guy is starting off down a route of DB access that will soon turn round to bite him..

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos exactly, better to go baby steps to try to solve it if you have no idea, ORM are an abstraction that has noting to add here, however was a problem with the packages at the end.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> All I did was create a new console app and enter this code to connect to DB.

So I can infer that you're using .NET Core, and so you need to add the NuGet package: System.Data.SqlClient

Your .csproj file should look like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.5.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Okay, I went to "ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2" folder and replaced the code in the .csproj with the code above, no more red lines under SqlConnection string.

Comment: In Visual Studio you can manage your NuGet dependencies by right-clicking on the "Dependencies" node under your project in the Solution Explorer, or by using the "Package Manager Console".  Of course editing the .csproj file is supported too.

Comment: I did the same as mentioned by @Peace! And the red lines under SqlConnection string went away. But, I cannot find the Form in the Design Mode anymore. On executing the .exe application the Windows Form comes up but no longer able to edit the Form in Design Mode. Any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: Ask a new question with the relevant information.